# Adding javaagent to process id or JVM start up

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

I want to add a java agent to process ID of the already running java application. Is there any way doing that using command line, something like

```
java -jar java agent.jar process_id
```

or if i can edit the hotspot JVM start up script directly to add the java agent there itself, but how can i edit the hotspot JVM start up script. I am using UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the sun JVM you can use the dynamic attach agent.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/attach/index.html